# inserting data if column value is equal to user input

Tags: sql

how can I do an if statement to check if the column value is equal to an input value a user entered

I have a table called Tasks and a primary key called TaskID. How would the "if" condition look like if I am trying to compare an id a user entered, to the TaskID column

basically I am trying to do if(TaskID = 599) insert values

I have tried this so far:

```
if ((select TaskID from MyDB.dbo.Tasks where TaskID=599) = 599)
begin
insert into MyDB.dbo.Tasks (Concluded)
Values (1)
end
```

however I don't think it has the result I want. It keeps creating a new task in stead.

Comment: are you trying to check if that value exists before inserting? and which RDBMS

Comment: I'm trying to see if "TaskID" is 599, if it is, then insert the "1" into the "Concluded" field

Comment: i think you need `update` not `insert`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM task WHERE taskid=599)
    UPDATE MyDB.dbo.Tasks SET concluded = 1 WHERE taskid=599
ELSE
    INSERT INTO MyDB.dbo.Tasks (concluded) VALUES (1)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to only check if the taskID already [exists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx) then use -

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 'x' FROM task WHERE taskid=599)
    UPDATE Table1 SET (...) WHERE Column1='SomeValue'
ELSE
    INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (...)
```